# Doesn't clear sandox after Quit game in IOS6

Tags: iphone, ios6, game-center, xcode4.6

I  created a turn based game by using game center.
When I quit the game , in sandbox it doesn't clear.
All quit games are listed in sandbox.
How can I clear the sandbox ?
 Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Try to reset you iOS simulator and then test.

Comment: Already reset simulator, it doesn't remove from device also.